# How can I amend my for-loop so that it does not stop after just one iteration?

Tags: python, loops, nlp, n-gram

I am trying to build a short program that goes through individual blocks of text, isolates the words that are nouns, processes each of these nouns individually through the [Google N-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) engine via an API, and pastes the results (how common that noun is as per the N-grams historical corpus) into a .csv.

I have successfully done this for a single block of text, but I am struggling to get my code to "move on" to a second one. The complication (at least for me) is that there are two for loops involved, one to specify the block of text, and another to specify the word to be processed through the N-grams engine. I am almost certain that my issue has something to do with this/the indentation, but I cannot for the life of me work out what is wrong...!

Below is the code as it stands. The output that I am getting in the .csv is correct, but as I say it only lists the *results_noun_final* for the nouns in the first row/block of text in my input. I have also pasted the csv input below.

Any tips hugely appreciated!

Thanks.

```
    DOTONET_input = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(DOTONET_input)

    for row in DOTONET_input:
        definition = str(row[2]).lower()
        dot_code = str(row[0])
        dot_title = str(row[1]).lower()
        fullwordlist = dotonet.stripNonAlphaNum(definition)
        wordlistnonum = [x for x in fullwordlist if not any(c.isdigit() for c in x)]
        wordlist = dotonet.removeStopwords(wordlistnonum, dotonet.stopwords)
        postagged = nltk.pos_tag(wordlist)
        postag = [lis[1] for lis in postagged]
        wordpostag = {wordlist[i]: postag[i] for i in range(len(wordlist))}
        #print(wordpostag)
        nouns = {key: val for key, val in wordpostag.items() if val == "NN" or val == "NNS" or val == "NNP" }
        nounslist = list(nouns.keys())
        #print(nouns)
        print(nounslist)
        #print(postag)

        for word in nounslist:

            url =f"https://books.google.com/ngrams/json?content={word}&year_start=1965&year_end=1975&corpus=26&smoothing=3"
            resp = requests.get(url)

            if resp.ok:
                results = json.loads(resp.content)[0]
                #print(results)
                results_clean = {key: val for key, val in results.items() if key == "ngram" or key =="timeseries"}
                #print(results_clean)
                timeseries = {key: results_clean[key] for key in results_clean.keys() & {'timeseries'}}
                timeseriesvalues= list(timeseries.values())
                timeseriesmean=np.mean(timeseriesvalues)
                #print(timeseriesmean)
                ngramsonly = {key: results_clean[key] for key in results_clean.keys() & {'ngram'}}
                ngramsvalues = list(ngramsonly.values())
                results_nouns_final={"dot_code": dot_code, "dot_title": dot_title, "word": ngramsvalues, "occurrence_mean": timeseriesmean}

                print(results_nouns_final)

                field_names=['dot_code', 'dot_title', 'word', 'occurrence_mean']
                with open("Measuring_specialization.csv", 'a') as csvfile:
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=field_names)
                    writer.writerows([results_nouns_final])
                continue
```

The CSV input I am using:

DOT_code,DOT_title,DOT_definition
001.061-010,ARCHITECT,"Researches, plans, designs, and administers building projects for clients, applying knowledge of design, construction procedures, zoning and building codes, and building materials. Consults with client to determine functional and spatial requirements of new structure or renovation, and prepares information regarding design, specifications, materials, color, equipment, estimated costs, and construction time. Plans layout of project and integrates engineering elements into unified design for client review and approval. Prepares scale drawings and contract documents for building contractors. Represents client in obtaining bids and awarding construction contracts. Administers construction contracts and conducts periodic on-site observation of work during construction to monitor compliance with plans. May prepare operating and maintenance manuals, studies, and reports. May use computer-assisted design software and equipment to prepare project designs and plans. May direct activities of workers engaged in preparing drawings and specification documents."
001.261-010,DRAFTER: ARCHITECTURAL,"Prepares detailed drawings of architectural designs and plans for buildings, according to specifications, sketches, and rough drafts provided by ARCHITECT 001.061-010. Draws rough and detailed sketches, drawings, and plans to scale [DRAFTER> Master Title]."

Comment: The indentation and the structure of nested loops seem fine. `continue` at the very end is not needed, but it will not create issues. You may want to check if all requests to Google API are going through, since the code will quietly skip a word if a request fails. Otherwise, it is difficult to say what may be wrong without a sample of input data.

Comment: Hi @bb1 . Thanks for your suggestion. I have checked if the issue was with the request going through to Google API by running the second block of text individually, and it gave me the results I expected. So the issue seems to be specifically when there is a second block of text/'row' in DOT_input to move onto, rather than with that second block itself. I have added a sample of the input CSV data to the post, in case you/anybody is able to take a closer look. If so, huge thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if this is the source of the problem, but I run the code (with small modifications) using the data you provided, and I noticed that several requests to the Google server were being rejected. They are probably being sent too fast. Try to add a pause (say, 1 second) before making each request. When I did it all requests went through. You may also want to add a code that retries a request if it fails, or at least produces some feedback that it happened.

Comment: Hi - thanks again for your suggestion. This may seem like an ignorant question - but how would I go about adding a pause to the code?

Comment: Add `from time import sleep` at the beginning of your code. Then in the inner `for` loop, after you make a request add `sleep(1)`. This will stop the program for 1 second.